# Pipe the first part of the request result to another host

Tags: node.js, stream

I want to download the first megabyte of a link, and then upload that to another server without putting any data on the disk.

What I have tried is this:

```
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: "#DIRECT_DOWNLOAD_LINK#",
  responseType: 'stream',
}).then((response) => {
  let sizeCounter = 0

  response.data.on('data', (newChunk) => {
    sizeCounter += newChunk.length
    if(sizeCounter > 1024000){
      response.data.emit('end')
    }
  })


  let formData = new FormData()
  form.append('file', response.data)

  axios({method: 'POST', data: formData, url: '#UPLOAD_URL#' headers: {...formData.getHeaders()}}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
  })
})
```

What happens here is that the first request looks like it has stopped, since the `data` event doesn't get called anymore. However, the next request only gets sent after the first request has finished downloading the whole file!

I have tried calling `response.data.destroy()` as well, but that doesn't work either.